# radio button group matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab, radio-button

i have two set of button groups.
first button groups has two radio buttons and second group has four radio buttons. 
if button 1 is selected in group1 and any one from the group 2. similarly for button2 in group 1 and any one from group2, respective function calls must be made on click of push button with these combinations. how to do it. there will be 8 separate function calls for their respective combinations. how to do the combination of button groups. switch case or if else statement did not work out?? kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.

First you create 2x4 cell array of your functions.

```
fnc_array = {fcn11, fcn12, fcn13, fcn14; fcn21, fcn22, fcn23, fcn24};
```

Then do `switch case` for each radio button in a group and return an index (say fcn_index1 for 1st group, and fcn_index2 for the 2nd group), which button selected.

Then you can call a function from your array with those indexes:

```
fcn_array{fcn_index1,fcn_index2}(arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch and if..else should certainly work out, but you need to nest them, i.e. there's no way to switch on a pair of values.

```
switch valA
    case 1
        if isB
            out = fcn11(args{:});
        else
            out = fcn12(args{:});
        end
    case 2
        if isB
            out = fcn21(args{:});
        else
            out = fcn22(args{:});
        end
    case 3
        if isB
            out = fcn31(args{:});
        else
            out = fcn32(args{:});
        end
    case 4
        if isB
            out = fcn41(args{:});
        else
            out = fcn42(args{:});
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest of style, but if they all use the same arguments then you could get away with dynamically building the call with the eval function based on which buttons were selected (using sprintf and the 'SelectedObject' field of the radio groups and a tag such as:`eval(sprintf('func%s%s(args)',get(get(handles.group1,'SelectedObject'),'Tag'),get(get(handles.group2,'SelectedObject'),'Tag'))`)

(Could be combined with indexing the children using `find(get(handles.group1,'Children')==get(handles.group2,'SelectedObject'))`
and taking note of which is which)